# Least expensive way to find the farthest DIVs?

Tags: javascript, css, html, position, dimensions

Let's say we have a container div of unknown `width` and `height` which is smaller than the full dimensions of the body.

This container div contains an **unknown number** of divs. All divs in the container are of **varying sizes** and apart from that have identical CSS as one of these 3 types:

- Type 1: All divs are floated to the left.
- Type 2: All divs are
  floated to the right.
- Type 3: All divs have unknown absolute
  positions, and can be even placed far off the screen.

Type 1 and 2 divs have margins and *may* have padding as well. Type 3 divs may have either, neither or both.

Given that the type of divs in the container is unknown - the ultimate goal is to add a secondary container, inside the original, large enough to accommodate all divs in the viewport (with overflow: scroll). **What is the least expensive way to calculate that?**

Some things to keep in mind:

1. divs **may or may not** (as a whole) have `box-sizing: border-box`. This will affect how their borders, margins and padding will be rendered and should be taken into account as well.
2. In cases of types 1 and 2 (floating divs), the divs are meant to stack horizontally - i.e., the container should grow to fit their total width. This should be taken into account.
3. A right margin on the rightmost div, for example, should be taken into calculation and should increase the container's width. This same goes for top-, bottom-, and leftmost divs.
4. IE8 and below is not required.
5. **Please use only vanilla Javascript**. No frameworks like jQuery etc.

Thanks!

Some visualizations:
[image: Type 1 (and 2) divs]
[image: Type 3 divs]

Comment: Why not just use `height:auto;` and `width:auto;`? That will ensure that the container div expands to fit all the children.

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Also, why don't you just use `overflow: auto;`?

Comment: I updated the question correctly and accordingly. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I will upload the updates pictures ASAP.

Comment: Are you really sure you must not use jQuery? In general I guess you'll have to run through all the child divs, calculate their offsets including margins and taking into account box-sizing and find the maximum offsets in all four directions, then calculate the dimensions for the div you need. I mean you'll have to rewrite a good part of jquery dimensions functionality and solve cross-browser inconsistencies which have been solved in jQuery for you long ago.

Comment: Will it still be that much of an endeavor if I said forget about IE below version 9?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do the performance testing yourself to see which method is fastest, but anyway here is one quite quick way. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7N2J/1/))

```
function getOuterBoxDimensions() {
    var original = document.getElementById('original'),
        divs = original.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        left = 0,
        right = original.offsetWidth,
        top = 0,
        bottom = original.offsetHeight;
    for (var i = 0, div; div = divs[i++];) {
        if (div.offsetTop < top) {
            top = div.offsetTop;
        }
        if (div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight > bottom) {
            bottom = div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight;
        }
        if (div.offsetLeft < left) {
            left = div.offsetLeft;
        }
        if (div.offsetLeft + div.offsetWidth > right) {
            right = div.offsetLeft + div.offsetWidth;
        }
    }
    return {
        top: top,
        left: left,
        bottom: bottom,
        right: right
    };
    // Note that dimensions are relative to the original div top left
}
```

As far as I know offsetLeft, offsetWidth etc. will return the right dimensions regardless of whether `box-sizing: border-box` is set or not. If you have divs within the interior divs then things will get a bit more complicated - you'll want to check only the divs that are childNodes of the original.

EDIT: Here is an extended version that properly takes into account margins and expands the new container to accommodate all floating divs in a single row (see discussion in comments). http://jsfiddle.net/m7N2J/10/

```
function getOuterBoxDimensions() {
    var original = document.getElementById('original'),
        divs = original.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        left = 0,
        right = original.offsetWidth,
        top = 0,
        bottom = original.offsetHeight,
        d = document.defaultView,
        style, marginTop, marginBottom, marginLeft, marginRight, float, floatWidth = 0;
    for (var i = 0, div; div = divs[i++];) {
        if (style = div.currentStyle) {
            // May be possible to exclude this if IE7/8 not needed
            marginTop = parseFloat(style.marginTop);
            marginBottom = parseFloat(style.marginBottom);
            marginLeft = parseFloat(style.marginLeft);
            marginRight = parseFloat(style.marginRight);
            float = style.float;
        }
        else {
            style = d.getComputedStyle(div, null);
            marginTop = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('margin-top'));
            marginBottom = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
            marginLeft = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('margin-left'));
            marginRight = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('margin-right'));
            float = style.getPropertyValue('float');
        }
        if (float == 'left' || float == 'right') {
            floatWidth += div.offsetWidth + marginLeft + marginRight;
            if (div.offsetHeight + marginBottom > bottom) {
                bottom = div.offsetHeight + marginBottom;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (div.offsetTop - marginTop < top) {
                top = div.offsetTop - marginTop;
            }
            if (div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight + marginBottom > bottom) {
                bottom = div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight + marginBottom;
            }
            if (div.offsetLeft < left - marginLeft) {
                left = div.offsetLeft - marginLeft;
            }
            if (div.offsetLeft + div.offsetWidth + marginRight > right) {
                right = div.offsetLeft + div.offsetWidth + marginRight;
            }
        }
    }
    if (right < left + floatWidth) {
        right = left + floatWidth;
    }
    return {
        top: top,
        left: left,
        bottom: bottom,
        right: right
    };
    // Note that dimensions are relative to the original div
}
```

Comment: Oh. I forgot that you want to include the margins too.

Comment: Finding the margins seems to be a lot more complicated -  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's very interesting. Please correct me if I'm wrong but your code will not take care of type 1 & 2 (floated), but only of type 3 (absolute) divs?

Comment: It should work no matter what the positioning is. But now you mention it, can you explain how the floated boxes overflow their container? Normally they will wrap onto a new 'row' http://jsfiddle.net/m7N2J/2/

Comment: Anyway this is the code with margins taken into account (not fully tested) http://jsfiddle.net/m7N2J/7/. Note that the issues discussed in the Quirksmode page I linked to may be a bit dated; IE9 and other modern browsers seem all to support `getComputedStyle` in a standard way.

Comment: Yes IE9 does support getComputedStyle. Regarding the floated divs — that is exactly what I am trying to find a solution for. With a container too small to fit, the floated elements would wrap into new lines. The script should handle this and calculate the required width to fit all the divs.

Comment: Okay, apologies for not reading your post carefully enough. What if there are both left and right floating divs; are they supposed all to line up in a single row?

Comment: I haven't thought of that but let's say for the matter that yes, they would all line up in a single row and what would separate them is the (optional) right margin on the last left floating div, and the left margin on the last right floating div - which would automatically occur if you are calculating the total width of new container correctly

Comment: Just saw your edit. I went through your solution on jsfiddle and apparently something is off (either the script or ME): My console reads: bottom: 497, left: -100, right: 634, top: 0. So total width is 734px. Now, 6 type 1 divs are 612px wide including the borders. + 1 type 2 div on the right is 122px. Add the type 3 div that's another 100 and we are at 836px total. Also the bottom is wrong - it should leave 50px (tallest div, type 1), while in practice it leaves more than 300px. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: The resulting width of 734px is correct - wide enough to contain all the floating divs. Remember the absolutely positioned div will not align with the floated ones but will appear on top/underneath. If you want them somehow to avoid overlapping then you have a lot more work to do, I'm afraid, because you have to figure out how the absolutely positioned and floating divs will line up together. The bottom is just that of the original box, as per your diagrams, because none of the inner divs is as tall as the original.

Comment: Yes I see now, I failed to see that the floating divs would float to that -100px as well. Props for an accurate solution. So now the question remains - is there a more efficient solution than this or not?